# Automatic git pull after git push on vps

Tags: git, automation, push, vps, pull

On my pterodactyl VPS, I don't have automatic git pull, which means I have to manually restart at each git push I make. I'd like to know how to make the restart automatic.

Please help.

I tried using GitHub webbooks which didn't work. it also looks like i cannot run commands on my server and it is setup in NodeJS

btw the server is to run a discord bot.